# How to specify wordpress to look for wp-content directory in a specific location other than default?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, configuration

I'm a rookie in wordpress and trying to setup a wordpress server. I have pre-defined content in a different file system(directory) but not in wordpress/wp-content dir.

Because of this when I try to access a url it gives out requested url is not found on this server.

Help me out where I can configure the wp-content path. So that I can update the new path.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can define a custom location for wp-content in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wpdirectory');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/wpdirectory');
```

Make sure you add that before the `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` line or it won't work

However, I'm not totally clear that's exactly what you want. What is your *pre-defined content*? If its not wordpress based it'll probably just break your site...

Comment: I tried adding your code into the wp-config.php as following,
    define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/var/www/html/public_html/my_site');
    define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/my_site');
Did I do it right? please let me know what I should be replacing in your code.

Comment: It didn't work. I got a blank page and page source is blank too

Comment: No, you should use the local, and the http address. So if your site is www.website.com and your wp-content is at www.website.com/my_site then you would use:

`define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/my_site');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.website.com/my_site');`